# What will happen if a link onMouseOut refer to a deferred javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, deferred

In my javascript menu.js, there is such a function:

```
    function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
      var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
    }
```

Then in my page, I use defer to include the script, as below:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="menu.js" defer></script>
```

Then after the script tag, there is a hyperlink, which refers to the javascript function, as below:

```
<a href="products.htm" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
```

since the javascript is deferred, what will happen if I move the mouse out the link when the javascript is not loaded yet? And how about using async with defer?

Thanks

Comment: You can't hover over the link before a deferred script is loaded.

Comment: @Teemu, sorry but I cannot understand very well. The link and the mouse are both ready, why I can't hover over the link?

Comment: The link won't be ready before the script. A script with `defer` attribute is loaded and run before `DOMContentLoaded` is triggered, before that there's no visible link to hover.